Arduino TFT_eSPI library Sprites not working as expected
I'm creating a project in platform.io using the Arduino header using a ESP32-2432S024 CYD Display. I've been trying to create some sprites which I ended up being able to do. The problem is that I'm constantly having to create my sprite object in the loop. I was following this tutorial here for adding sprites: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U4jOFLFNZBI&t=384s&ab_channel=VolosProjects where this was not required.
Does anyone have any idea why this is required or if I'm doing something wrong causing this to be needed.
#include "game.h"

/**
 * DONT FORGET TO CHANGE THE USER_SETUP.H IN THE TFT_eSPI lib 
 */

void Game::Init()
{
    // Start the tft display and set it to black
    tft.init();
    tft.setRotation(1); //This is the display in landscape
    tft.setSwapBytes(true);

    // Clear the screen before writing to it
    tft.fillScreen(TFT_BLACK);
}


float x = 50;
float y = 50;
void Game::Loop()
{
    background.createSprite(screenWidth, screenHeight);
    background.setSwapBytes(true); // Correct color
    background.setColorDepth(8);
    background.pushImage(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight, backgroundSprite);

    cursor.createSprite(16,16);
    cursor.setColorDepth(8);    
    cursor.pushImage(0, 0, 16, 16, cursorSprite);
    cursor.pushToSprite(&background, x, y, TFT_BLACK); 
    
    background.pushSprite(0,0);

    x++;
    y++;
    if (x > screenWidth) {
        x = 0;
    }
    if (y > screenHeight) {
        y = 0;
    }
}

#ifndef GAME_H
#define GAME_H

#include "Arduino.h"
#include <TFT_eSPI.h>
#include "sprites/cursor.h"
#include "sprites/background.h"

class Game 
{
    public:
        void Init();
        void Loop();
    private:
        TFT_eSPI tft = TFT_eSPI();
        TFT_eSprite cursor = TFT_eSprite(&tft);
        TFT_eSprite background = TFT_eSprite(&tft);
        TFT_eSprite gyroText = TFT_eSprite(&tft);
        float screenWidth = 320;
        float screenHeight = 240;
};

#endif

I've tried moving:
    background.createSprite(screenWidth, screenHeight);
    background.setSwapBytes(true); // Correct color
    background.setColorDepth(8);

into the Init() function but this causes the screen to go black the same happends when I try this with:
    cursor.createSprite(16,16);
    cursor.setColorDepth(8);

When attempting to move any of these lines out of the Loop and into Init it causes the screen to no longer show anything and just have a black screen.

I found the answer on this post: Display Issue with TFT_eSPI.h Library: Sprite Not Displaying Correctly After Adjusting Dimensions
Moving the function setColorDepth(8) above the createSprite() function seems to have fixed it!
